# How to extarct the max value of a multi row table with the same ID's

Tags: mysql

i want to make a MySQL request that return the max value of a multi row table with the same id here's an example :

```
ID | VALUE
A      1
B      1
A      2
B      3
```

The result request must be like :

```
  ID | VALUE
  A      2
  B      3
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

As simply as:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/764d6/1/0)**

```
SELECT ID, MAX(`VALUE`) AS `VALUE`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: @karimkarim Great, read about `GROUP BY` and aggregate function for more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max ;)